# At91bootstrap is not loading application code

Tags: linux, bootloader, atmel

I have compiled At91bootstrap bootloader for sama5d3 processor using instruction given on website linux4sam. I am trying to load application directly after bootstrap bypassing uboot 3 stage bootloader binary. In menuconfig, i have seclected option "load 4MB of memory in start of RAM" after bootstrap binary. My bootloader logs are coming but it stops at certain point and application is not starting.I am using serial flash to dump boot binary code in it.

logs are like that

AT91Bootstrap 4.0.6-dirty (2023-06-22 15:16:34)

SF: Got Manufacturer and Device ID: 0xef 0x70 0x17 0x0 0x0

SF: Copy 0x200000 bytes from 0x40000 to 0x26f00000

SF: Done to load image

please help me. Thanks in advance

i have tried

1. change the configuration of dram in menuconfig.
2. change the flash offset, demo image size and external ram address.
3. define jump address in main.c
4. Read config files in source code and trying to find external ram address.

Comment: "*i have seclected option "load 4MB of memory in start of RAM"*" -- Unless your board's RAM starts at the very peculiar address of `0x26f00000`, the log that you posted does not match that configuration. Of course that could be just one of several possible concurrent issues, e.g. how did you build this application?